# Using HttpWebRequest on mono 3.2.8 Ubuntu Server 14

Tags: c#, multithreading, ubuntu, mono, garbage-collection

I have a console app that creates 500 threads and each thread pulls urls off of a concurrent stack and creates HttpWebRequest objects, gets a response and logs the time. I've run this program on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box with 512 MB of RAM and it works fine.

I've tried using IO completion ports (async methods) but have gotten way worse performance, so that is not an option for me right now.

Running on Ubuntu Server 14 64 bit (1 GB of RAM) causes the following errors to be shown:

```
Warning: Degraded allocation.  Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists.
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x1f (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x91 (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0xb (error 10022)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x6c (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x6b (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x1c (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x1b (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0xbd (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x31 (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x1a2 (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x187 (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x18c (error 10038)
Warning: Degraded allocation.  Consider increasing nursery-size if the warning persists.
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0xa5
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x141 (error 10038)
_wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x44
```

Here is the code that creates the web request:

```
private static HttpWebRequest CreateRequest(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36";
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    req.KeepAlive = false;
    req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
    req.Timeout = 5000;
    req.Proxy = null;

    return req;
}
```

Thread creation code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string url;
    while (urlsToPull.TryPop(out url))
    {
        try
        {
            Stopwatch indiv = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            using (HttpWebResponse res = CreateRequest(url).GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref badStatus);
                }
            }
            indiv.Stop();
            Add(ref urlSum, indiv.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            lock (goodFile)
            {
                goodFile.WriteLine(url);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            lock (errorFile)
            {
                errorFile.WriteLine(url);
            }
            Interlocked.Increment(ref errors);
        }
        Interlocked.Increment(ref urlsChecked);
    }
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref tasks);
    s.Stop();
}, 4096);
```

Can the nursery size be changed via the mono command line? I am not sure what the problem is with the error looking up socket handle, but maybe it's related to the nursery error?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To configure the nursery size from the command line, use the MONO_GC_PARAMS environment variable, ex: MONO_GC_PARAMS=nursery-size=16m

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest updating your mono version to the very latest. Microsoft also updated .NET to be open source, so you may want to try back if/when the mono team integrates this particular code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server is not behind a firewall? Turn all firewalls including windows firewall off in a test environment and then try to reconnect.

Comment: Not using Windows, using Ubuntu Server with no firewall